# NodeSet cannot be resolved to a type in android

Tags: android, xml

I want to execute an xpath query

i added

```
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
```

and i used this code

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/books/book";
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource("books.xml");
NodeSet nodes =(NodeSet) xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

I used [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) documentation

but an error `NodeSet cannot be resolved to a type` is displayed

Thank you in advance

**Update**

I chaged the code to:

```
XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    // To get an instance of the XPathFactory object itself.
    XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
    // Create an instance of XPath from the factory class.
    String expression = "/books/book";
    XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(expression);

    // Compile the expression to get a XPathExpression object.
    Object result = xPathExpression.evaluate(R.raw.books);
    //Evaluate the expression against the XML Document to get the result.
```

But an error displayed in this lines

```
XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(expression);
    Object result = xPathExpression.evaluate(R.raw.books);
```

`xPath.compile(expression);` and `xPathExpression.evaluate(R.raw.books);`errors

what i do now?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/XPathConstants.html#NODESET)
the java representation of `NodeSet` is `NodeList`. You can try to replace `NodeSet` with `NodeList`.

```
NodeList nodes =(NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Comment: an error in xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);